# Find the Expected Value of the Matrix Expression: $\mathbb{E}[(x - a)^TB(x - a)]$

Tags: probability, matrices

The question is to find $\mathbb{E}[(x - a)^TB(x - a)]$, provided that $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$.

I have found the solution in the [MatrixCookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf), which turns out to be $(\mu - a)^TB(\mu - a) + tr(B\Sigma)$. However, I'm interested in the derivation of that result. Yet, I am failing to approach the solution. I would appreciate hints and tips.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the same answer as @JohnDawkins already wrote, but in matrix form.

I guess everything is real here and $B$ is symmetric. Rewrite first
\begin{align}
(x-a)^TB(x-a)&=(x-\mu+\mu-a)^TB(x-\mu+\mu-a)=\\
&=(x-\mu)^TB(x-\mu)+2(\mu-a)^TB(x-\mu)+(\mu-a)^TB(\mu-a).
\end{align}
Taking the mean value, the second term vanishes since $\mathbb{E}(x-\mu)=0$. In the first term we use the trace property $\text{tr}(AC)=\text{tr}(CA)$
$$
\mathbb{E}\underbrace{(x-\mu)^T}_{A}\underbrace{B(x-\mu)}_{C}=\mathbb{E}\,\text{tr}(B(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^T)=\text{tr}(B\cdot\underbrace{\mathbb{E}(x-\mu)(x-\mu^T)}_{\Sigma})
$$
and you get the result.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: (i) Write $(x-a)^TB(x-a)$ as a double sum and then take the expectation of each term in the sum, (ii) use the given information that $\Bbb E[x_j]=\mu_j$ and $\Bbb E[x_ix_j]=\Sigma_{i,j}+\mu_i\mu_j$. (The symmetry of the covariance matrix will be used eventually.)